# How call SOAP based web-Service using PhoneGap in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, web-services, soap, cordova

I am newbie for PhoneGap and our client's requirement is to access SOAP based web-service in iPhone using PhoneGap, basically accessing the web-service using javascript, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: see this link http://kmithi.blogspot.in/2012/02/callling-web-services-in.html

Answer (score 4):

calling a webservice with phonegap is the same than calling it directly from your browser (but you have to think about the same orign policy).

Some performance implications are here to consider was well because processing big chunks of xml in javascript on mobile phones might be slow. So you could use some kind of weserver to talk to the webservice end send some simplified json to your phone or you can take a look at this tutorial from ibm describing how to call a webservice directly from javascript:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-wsajax/

Answer (score 1):

as i know, call web service from mobile device just like call web service from out side of that web service. So we need cross domain.
To cross domain, we need the support from server side, such as: Jsonp or proxy