# How to parse xmlwebservice in phonegap

Tags: css, html, cordova

I am new in phonegap development. I am making one platform independent mobile application by use of HTML5,CSS . I want to call xml based webservice in my phonegap application and wants to parse that service. Please, any body suggest me how is it possible with simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in this answer:

[How call SOAP based web-Service using PhoneGap in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974295/how-call-soap-based-web-service-using-phonegap-in-iphone/5981851#5981851)

"calling a webservice with phonegap is the same than calling it directly from your browser" (except he is incorrect about the same domain policy as PhoneGap apps are loaded via file:// reference and are thus exempt).

Perhaps the link in his answer could help?

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-wsajax/