# How to Consume WSDL webservice in Phone Gap for ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, wsdl, cordova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How call SOAP based web-Service using PhoneGap in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974295/how-call-soap-based-web-service-using-phonegap-in-iphone)

I am new to Phone Gap and i have to make SOAP request and consume WSDL webservices in Phone gap.
I have found that there isn't Cross Domain Issue while calling the webservices with Phone Gap.
Please provide me any link or code.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Following are few links:

1. [Link 1](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/32513809/Simple%20Web%20Service%20Consumption%20with%20PhoneGap%20and%20XUI)
2. [Link 2](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/msg/e2c3ebad3940bf58)

Basic idea: You might need to write a json wrapper around the soap web service so the 
phone side can send/recieve requests.

Example: phone send JSON -> server parses JSON -> server call SOAP with JSON data 
-> server parse SOAP response -> server format JSON reposnse -> phone 
process JSON response