# How to call SOAP service from Phonegap (iPhone app)

Tags: iphone, soap, cordova

I am trying to call a SOAP service using [this SOAP client](http://www.guru4.net/articoli/javascript-soap-client/en/) but it is not working for me. Please help me. How can I send and receive XML SOAP with Phonegap?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How call SOAP based web-Service using PhoneGap in iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974295/how-call-soap-based-web-service-using-phonegap-in-iphone)

Comment: I saw the your mentioned link. I tried that but it doesn't work for me. I want soap specific example.

Comment: That doesn't mean it's not the same question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Phonegap is HTML/JS/CSS commonly communicating via XHR/Ajax. It's better to use **jQuery Ajax** functions. You can get the details [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Eg:

[Posting-XML-SOAP-Requests](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1853-Posting-XML-SOAP-Requests-With-jQuery.htm)

[AJAX-Requests-Between-jQuery](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2327-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-CORS-AJAX-Requests-Between-jQuery-And-Node-js.htm)

[Simple jQuery client to call a SOAP web service](http://leonidius2010.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/98/)

If you find any cross-domain issues (or working in a browser and not working with simulator/device), please refer to the below steps.

Go to the **Resources** folder, you can see a file named **Cordova.plist**. Click on that and you can see the **Root** elements. Right click on the Root, add a row, set the key as **ExternalHosts** with type **Array**.

Expand the item, and add an item as **item0**. Give it type **string** and enter the value as '*'.

Don't forget to save the Cordova.plist after changes (just use cmd+s).

Comment: Can I create SOAP request and collect SOAP response using Jquery Ajax?