# How to call Soap Web services in PhoneGap(Android)

Tags: cordova, soap, android-ksoap2

I want to create soap services and call from android Phone gap..I dont know where to start from...can any one say regarding this...

can anyone refer me any sample tutorial or an example to do so.. 
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

[How to call SOAP service from Phonegap (iPhone app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542195/how-to-call-soap-service-from-phonegap-iphone-app)

Comment: the method is same as you are using html and js for phonegap app. I used that method and it works well in my blackberry app.

Comment: You can improve your "link only answer" by including relevant details within the answer itself.