# How to call android Soap Web services in PhoneGap(Android)

Tags: java, android, web-services, cordova, ksoap2

I want to create soap services and call from android Phone gap..I dont know where to start from...can any one say regarding this...

can anyone refer me any sample tutorial or an example to do so.. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery for your requirement

For details check these links,

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1853-Posting-XML-SOAP-Requests-With-jQuery.htm

http://openlandscape.net/2009/09/25/call-soap-xm-web-services-with-jquery-ajax/

http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-web-services-with-jquery.aspx

[How to call SOAP service from Phonegap (iPhone app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542195/how-to-call-soap-service-from-phonegap-iphone-app)

http://kmithi.blogspot.in/2012/02/callling-web-services-in.html

Comment: I am now to this technology Raghav..ALl the links just increase my Complexity to understand Phonegap....I would appreciate if   u provide me a tutorial that calls web services from phone gap(android)...

Comment: Thats fine but u need to research a bit before you ask the question. we have a lot of information available on the Internet based on your requirement.

Comment: Raghav can you provide a sample login application So that I can start my work..Can you send it to my emailiD:-muhammedsarfarazali@gmail.com..thanks