# integrating phonegap with mysql database

Tags: mysql, cordova

I have a dynamic website. It uses mysql database which is provided by the hosting team. I need my android app to use the same database. How could I integrate the same.?

Comment: quite broad question. While there are tons of answers, you can look to implement REST on server side

Comment: i uses rest api for the same. For website purpose, I use angulajs $http method for accessing the rest api. Can I use the same $http method in phonegap?

Comment: so you are on the right way, have a  look here [How to call SOAP service from Phonegap (iPhone app)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542195/how-to-call-soap-service-from-phonegap-iphone-app) there is an interesting answer with some links. Basically your app will call a webservice and retrieve JSON / XML or something else...

Answer (score 0):

An Ajax request in Cordova/Phonegap is the same as using the standard jQuery:

For retrieving data I used in my app [minimalist code]:

```
  $.getJSON(url).done(function (jsonData) {
                console.debug('retrieved JSON');
                // process your data here
            }).fail(function () {
                console.debug('cannot retrieve remote URL');
                // error occurred
            });
```

See also here: [Calling a REST service from a Cordova application using jQuery](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/victorsh/entry/march_11_2014_8_58_pm?lang=en) and othere questions here in SO such as: [How to call SOAP service from Phonegap (iPhone app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542195/how-to-call-soap-service-from-phonegap-iphone-app).