# How to call soap based web service in cordova

Tags: web-services, cordova, soap

can you please tell me how to call soap based web service in Cordova.?
actually i have some methods  having parameter in web service want to call that those methods, can you please help me.

in my web service i want to call web method ==> https://gnwebitga.austin.hp.com/gnws.net/GNewton.Internal.WS/GNAgreementService/GNAgreementService.svc?wsdl

i want to call soap based web service i got simple way to call web service from this url==>
[Simplest SOAP example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript[)^]

But i don't understand where to add method name so that it call that method from service, in web service there are some method which i want to call but unable to call

can you please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It better to jQuery AJAX for any interactions with webservice in cordova application.

More details can be found at following links:

- [Posting-XML-SOAP-Requests](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1853-posting-xml-soap-requests-with-jquery.htm)
- [jQuery Client for SOAP service](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1853-posting-xml-soap-requests-with-jquery.htm)

Also i suggest you look at the following [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542195/how-to-call-soap-service-from-phonegap-iphone-app) which is helpful.

Comment: @chaimAmine I dont understand what you mean.

Comment: i want to call soap based web service IN HTML CODE :)

Comment: @chaimAmine of course the links I shared, details about calling soap service from JavaScript which in turn is called in HTML.. Not sure what you want